# Show columns in calendar

Tags: list, calendar

How can I specify, which columns (or attributes) to show in a calendar view?

Suppose I have a calendar event:

[image: event]

It starts at 17.00, ends at 18.00 and its title is "weg".
Now I want its other attributes, such as location, description, category, etc. to be shown just under the title. So I need further information of the event without clicking on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a calculated column that concatenates all this information into a single field, then in the view settings for the calendar, you can set this calculated as the title.